# What challenges does scala feature warnings mend

Tags: scala

I have a number of feature warnings in my application i.e. 'reflective access', 'implicit conversion' and 'postfix operator'. This can be fixed by importing various scala.language features.

But what does this mean? Why do the scala compiler want me to be explicit about these? The compiler can obviously see that I'm using these features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these flags are documented in the `scala.language` object.

Reflective access can have surprising performance and is unusable in some environments (e.g. containers with a strict security policy, or it can cause difficulties on Android). So it's worth being explicit about.

Supporting postfix operators creates ambiguities in parsing. I think the longer term plan (and I don't speak for Typesafe here) is to stop supporting postfix operators in files that don't explicitly enable that support. That would make for more consistent parsing of code like:

```
a b
{
  ...
```

where it's currently ambiguous whether `b` is a postfix operator or a method that takes the following block as an argument.

Some people find implicit conversions confusing, and some organizations ban their use as a matter of policy. Having an explicit flag warns a reader that this file contains implicit conversions.

Honestly I think this move is motivated at least partially by politics - implicits and ambiguous syntax are common points for superficial criticism of scala - but for Typesafe in particular, gaining acceptance of scala by "enterprise" users is a major goal, and making it possible to "turn off" certain features may be a pragmatic step towards that. If you're happy to use these features ubiquitously, I'd advise just configuring the relevant compiler arguments (e.g. `-language:implicitConversions`).